# Running error opening app when deploying; uses a Github Watson Voice Bot tutorial

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, ibm-cloud-plugin

https://github.com/IBM/watson-voice-bot

I am fairly new to using Watson Assistant + IBM CLI but am trying to link a Watson Assistant to IBM's speech to text plugin/API. There's a great tutorial provided on GitHub, but I have run into problems trying to deploy the app, and have been unable to get any assistance so far (from people on Github).

```
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs watson-voice-bot-20181121030328640 --recent' for more information

Finished: FAILED
```

This is what occurs as I try to deploy it. What should I do? 
[image]

Comment: How did you try to deploy the app? Was it using the toolchain and deploy button? Which region?

Comment: Yes using the toolchain and deploy button. Region was Dallas